# Save Image from URL. Fails inside a loop, but not when run once

Tags: image, vbscript, asp-classic

This Function works:

```
Sub SaveImage(url, name)
    ' Set your settings
    strFileURL = url
    strHDLocation = "D:\Images\" & name

    ' Fetch the file
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I call it once, it download the image, if I put it inside a loop it fail with different errors.
I set this function in a page, and set the URL and image name, then it download the image.
I have permission to everyone. NO PERMISSION ISSUE.
If I put it in a seperate page, then take the URL and image name from request, as:

```
Dim url, name
url = Request("url")
name = Request("name")
```

Then call the function:

```
Call SaveImage(url, name)
```

I get:

```
ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc'
Write to file failed.
```

If I call it from the page, like this:

```
Call SaveImage("http://www.example.com/images/imageName.jpg", "imageName.jpg")
```

It dose download the image.

But if from the same place, I call the sub from inside a loop, like this:
Variables are declared above. Array is filled.

```
For row = 0 To UBound(myArray, 2)
    url = CStr(ar(1, row)) : image = id & ".jpg"
    Call SaveImage2(url, image)
Next
```

It fail in the first image.

```
ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc'
Write to file failed.
```

I tried others stream writers, but others act the same with different errors.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but try `objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation, adSaveCreateOverWrite`

Comment: @John use also `Const adSaveCreateOverWrite=2` as enumerated constants are not (intrinsic) present by default and need to be defined before using in _VBScript_.

Comment: Are you getting the url and name from the query string or a form?  Because if it is coming from the query string, the encoding could be your issue.

Comment: I have loaded it from a csv file, then loop through it.
I thought so.
I have posted the text of URL to the page, then copy from the page to a function as one time, then it worked.
I got me angry so I dropped ASP and made my solution with .NET.
Technically, I don't have an issue now.
Thank you though.

Comment: @JosefZ There is no need to explicitly define them, they exist in the DLL afterall you just have to tell Classic ASP to look for them. See [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml).

Comment: Are you using *"exotic"* image name which will probably make the ADODB.Stream spit it's dummy? Do you have an example of a URL you request that fails?